# Negative Mahalanobis distance

Tags: matrices, statistics

I am using Mahalanobis distance to compute a observation say: $x$ to a bunch of observations say: $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\}$for classification.

$\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\}$ has mean $m$ and covariance matrix $C$

The problem is that:

$d^2 = (x - m)^T C^{-1} (x - m)$  is negative.

The negative number is:
$-3.5796e+17$

I find the values in the covariance matrix is quite small, the max among them is only: $6.9977e-05$

The negative is quite like an overflow of a number close to zeros, thus big negative number.

I am thinking of doing some adjustment in the observations(features) $\{ x_1, x_2, ..., x_k\}$, so that the covariance matrix $C$ can be better for calculating Mahalanobis distance.

Does anyone have comments or suggestions? I would be really appreciate your kind help.

Comment: Also whilst at it. Did you use a tolerance level when computing the covariance matrix?

Comment: the min value of covariance matrix is $-6.4193e-05$ and $-2.0391e+22$ for inverse covariance matrix. do you have suggestion to overcome it, and help to calculate the mahalanobis distance, since that is the goal.

Comment: I don't use the tolerance level. Currently the code is using numpy.

Comment: My previous comments are mute in terms of the negative nature of elements. but I think you do have floating point error.

Comment: Yes, I also hope my guess was correct. Thanks for the detailed analysis. Do you have any idea on adjusting the covariance matrix, either how to normalise the features vectors or float error avoiding tips?

Comment: It is difficult to say. I would at first try a strict threshold(tolerance) on how small the elements of the threshold can be. What is the min max of your feature vectors? maybe you can use that, as you said, and normalize to make the co-variance more manageable?

Comment: The $l_2$ normalization ($x_i \leftarrow x_i ~/~  \|x_i\|_2 $ ) does not seem to work, the resulted covariance matrix is still small. the min max of my feature vectors are $-0.0299$ and $0.0217$ respectively.